# setcookie not working on safari and firefox

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I'm trying to set cookies on my project, but it is not working on Safari or Firefox.

I get results on Google Chrome though.

Here is my code:

```
 setcookie('mycookiename', 'data', time()+60*60*24*365, '/', false);
 print_r($_COOKIE['mycookiename']);
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: pass the domain as the last param (not false)
what hostname are you using?  localhost, 127.0.0.1, www.somethingelse.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code work properly

```
setcookie("mycookiename", 'data', time()+60*60*24*365, "/", "", "", TRUE);
print_r($_COOKIE['mycookiename']);
```

Comment: Refresh your browser and check

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because of ajax and fetch.

fetch won’t send cookies, unless you set the credentials init option:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {...},
    ...
  });
```

also if you're doing a cross origin request, it seems you should set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header as well. see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40255834/4718434

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes i have this problem, when i using lowercase names of Cookie, for example *"geoLoсationCode"*. It's work for Safari when i change to uppercase *"GEO_LOCATION_CODE*".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).