# Set-Cookie from Remote API not working

Tags: javascript, http, express, cookies

I'm currently on project that needs to use an httpOnly cookie. The project requires a direct call to the API.

Let's say it's `xxx.com/vx/auth/login` that authenticates user login attempt. That endpoint will give response and also set-cookie to the client. Something like this:

`Set-Cookie:token=eyJ0b2tlbiI6ImV5SmhiR2NpT2lKSVV6STFOaUlzSW5SNWNDSTZJa3BYVkNKOS5leUoxYVdRaU9pSXhNREEwT0RJd05DSXNJbDlwWkNaNkluWXhYM1Z6WlhKekx6RXdNRFE0TWpBMElpd2libUZ0WlNJNklrRm5kVzVuSUZOMWNubGhJRUpoYm1kellTSXNJbVZ0WVdsc0lqb2ljR0ZwYm1GdVpHVnpkR2x1WldSQWVXRm9iMjh1WTI5ddlpd2liR1YyWld3aU9qQXNJbWxoZENJNk1UUTNOek0zTVRnMk55d2laWGh3SWpveE5EYzNOVFEwTmpZc2ZRLmtUN0IzNW9YYjQ2RmU3WWFLYkd4MXhoYkdGUWJ1TFg1U053N3FWSjNfa2siffQ==; expires=Thu, 27 Oct 2016 05:04:27 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly`

But when I look at the `devtools`, the cookie is not set. Even after I refresh several times.

What do I miss here? Do I need to create a proxy to handle this? * I used to use proxy and it works well

Comment: Browsers sometimes don't show it. Is it sent back with the next response?

Comment: Yes, it is. As mentioned in the question, one of the response-header is 'set-cookie'.

Comment: so what is your question? if it's sent back, it's working

Comment: In my case, the cookie isn't set at all even though there's  a set-cookie header from the response. What do I miss here?

Comment: when you send request to server after the request with `set-cookie`, what's inside `cookie:` header?

Comment: There is no  ```cookie``` headers found and sent in the next requests.. :-/

Comment: are you working on backend as well?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this problem by coordinating with the backend engineer guy:

1. Remove wildcard from Access-Control-Allow-Origin and use specific domain origin instead. If not,
2. Set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`

And in the request, I set `withCredentials` to `true`.

NOTE: If you set `withCredentials` to `true`, you have to set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to `true` also. Plus, this won't work if you still use wildcard in your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

[Further reading about "Request With Credentials"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials)

Comment: Ahh, man, I spent couple hours to make it work, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, I made something like this.

```js
//API REST ROUTE
app.get('/login', function(req, res){ 
    console.log('login route', process.env.NODE_ENV);
    const token = '*/*--=3432432$%^%$'
    
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin); //req.headers.origin
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    // access-control-expose-headers allows JS in the browser to see headers other than the default 7
    res.set(
        'Access-Control-Expose-Headers',
        'date, etag, access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-credentials'
    );
    
    res
        .cookie('rest-auth-cookie', token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            // secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
            sameSite: 'strict',
            // maxAge: 100,
            path: '/'
          })
        .status(200)
        .json({message: 'success'})
});
```

and

```js
// Client Page
const loginAction = function() {
        let req = new Request(REMOTE_LOGIN_URL, {
          mode: 'cors', //just a safe-guard indicating our intentions of what to allow
          credentials: 'include', //when will the cookies and authorization header be sent
        });
    const apiRestLogin = function() {
      fetch(req)
        .then(resp => {
          console.log('resp', resp);
          
          return resp.json()
        }).then(resp => {
            console.log(resp)
            // router.push('/');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i was using same domain (no-cors).

i figured out : fetch won’t send cookies, unless you set the credentials init option:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {...},
    ...
  });
```